# getElementbyId for items in a div

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been having trouble understanding why my "document.getElementbyID()" function is breaking my external script. My script and html file look like this:

```js
function validateRegCat(obj)
 {
  setRegCat(obj);
  var invalid = false;
  if(obj.value == "Invalid")
  {
  alert("Please select a Registration category")
  invalid = true;
  }
  return invalid;
  
 } 

function setRegCat(obj)
 {
 if(obj.value == "UWSStudent")
 {
  document.getElementbyId("Institution").value = "The University of Western Sydney";
  document.getElementbyId("Institution").readOnly = true;
 }
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <form class="Application" action"prac1task3Form.asp" method="post" onsubmit="return finalValidate(this);" >
   <div class="PersonalDetails">
    <fieldset>
                <legend>
      <h3>Personal Details</h3>
    </legend>
    <!--Kept in a list to keep the form looking neat and organised-->
    <ul>  
                  <li>
                    <!-- Create a selection box for the user to input their Registration Category-->
                      <label for="RegCat"><strong>Registration Category:</strong><sup>*</sup></label>
                       <select name="RegCat" size="1" onblur="validateRegCat(this); setRegCat(this)" required>
                        <option value = "Invalid">--Choose a registration category--</option>
                        <option value = "UWSStudent">UWS Student</option>
                        <option value = "OtherStudent">Student at another Institution</option>
                        <option value = "UWSAcademic">UWS Academic</option>
                        <option value = "UWSStaff">UWS Staff</option>
                        <option value = "OtherAcademic">Academic from another Institution</option>
                        <option value = "PublicMember">Member of the public</option>
                        <option value = "Retired">Retired</option>
                      </select>
                   </li>
                  <!-- Input Institution. Sets automatically to Uws and readonly if certain registration categorys     are selected-->
        <li> 
       <label for="Institution"><strong>Institution of learning/work:</strong> </label>
                      <input type="text" name="Institution" id="Institution" size="30" maxlength="30"/>
     </li> 
                 </ul> 
                 </fieldset> 
   </div>  
  </form>
</body>
```

I've cut the html down to only the relevant parts. What I want the script to do is to change the value of the "Institution" text input to read only and set the text displayed. However I've found that the "document.getElementbyId("Institution")" breaks the script. The script runs fine before that and when I change those lines to meaningless things such as alerts, the script functions and returns as it should.

Comment: There is some Uncaught ReferenceError: validateRegCat is not defined, first fix that.

Comment: You should check your JavaScript console for errors next time. The specific error is *"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"*. This is due to the typo as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is related to typos (make sure you have capital 'B' instead of 'b'): `document.getElementById` (https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

If you use Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) or similar while developing you can detect these small errors easily.